# Going to Legoland Denmark with my family, what should I do/get?

Tags: shopping, legoland

Hello fellow LEGO lovers! I know this question is not entirely what this site is for but I figured I'd ask because I want to hear what you have to say.

I have been wanting to go to the original Denmark Legoland for 40 years and I finally have my chance. This August I will be going to Copenhagen for a few weeks with my family (kids 7 & 4) and will be spending several days at Legoland.

My questions for you are:

1. What activities and exhibits are unique to this Legoland that I should be sure of seeing? Obviously every Legoland's features are different but since this will likely be the only time I ever go there, I want to focus on what I know I can get nowhere else.
2. I will likely be bringing an extra bag just to fill with LEGO. Are there sets, parts, or other LEGO related items for sale there and nowhere else? I'd consider buying things in areas I don't normally focus on if its the only place I can get them. What about pricing, is it better there because its closer to their Denmark factory?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Just a head's up: We've had some [discussions in the past](http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/q/203/56) about whether questions about the parks are On or Off Topic, so I'm leaving this one for now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to disappoint you sir.

But first of all LEGOLAND in Denmark is about 3 hour drive from Copenhagen, I am from Denmark and I would say that the Danish LEGOLAND is not that great, they do not have any really special stuff that you cannot get anywhere else, in fact when I was in Florida LEGOLAND I found that they had a lot more unique stuff then the Danish one.

They do have a website for the danish LEGOLAND http://www.legoland.dk/en/Explore/

The best things I like about the Danish LEGOLAND and the thing I would advise one to look at in there are:

1. Their models, they have made some beautiful models of different stuff in there only made out of LEGO.
2. Their workshop, they have a nice workshop where they show young children what you are able to do with LEGO Mindstorms and help them make some small programs.
3. See if you can be there while they have [one of their events](http://www.legoland.dk/en/Plan/Events/).

Good luck and have a nice vacation :)

Comment: Thanks for the information! Yeah I knew it would be a long train ride so we're likely going to stay overnight locally (probably will spring for the Legoland hotel). A surprise that there aren't many unique items to get, that's a disappointment. I'll probably still buy a T-shirt! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Another important point to note about all of the Parks shops:

Whilst the on site are not actually LEGO Store shops - they are (albeit usually well stocked) franchise shops - as such they typically only carry general availability and "Hard to find" LEGO Sets and merchandise - LEGO Store and Shop@Home "Exclusive" items are not available through these stores.

Also your LEGO VIP Card (if you have one) [will not be usable in them](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/VIP/vipFaq.jsp#12).

Comment: Ah good to know. I went to the Westchester, NY mini-legoland and was shocked at how expensive the LEGO was there, was hoping the Danish Legoland was different. So perhaps I'll buy some LEGO at the large Copenhagen LEGO store instead. Thanks!